# React (Map , Axios , useState) add usestae new value using map with axios

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

here is a usestate so I want to add more customers using map

```
 useEffect(() => {   
     getApiDAta()
     async function getApiDAta() {
         try {
           const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/customer/')
           .then(res => {setcustName(res.data)
           custName.map((items) => { 
             setSuggestions([items.firstname])
             console.log(suggestions);
             })

         })
           
         } catch (error) {
           console.error(error);
         }
       }
 },[]);
```

```
const [custName,setcustName] = useState([])
   const [suggestions,setSuggestions] = useState(
        custName.map((items) => {
          return   [`${items.name}`];
       })
    );
```

I want to multiple item in suggestions so please help me

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to map an empty array. Try to map it after its filled:

```
custName.map((items) => {
      return [`${items.name}`];
   })
```